# Why do I see FTP prompt when I do not have any FTP server running on my machine?

Tags: windows, ftp

Why do I see the `ftp prompt` when I do not have any `FTP Server` running on my machine ?

When I do :

```
C:\Users\user>ftp localhost
ftp>
```

I see the ftp prompt ?

Answer (score 1):

The `ftp` command always shows you a prompt, whether or not it's connected. There's an `open` command you can give at this prompt to open a connection.

When I'm trying to do `ftp localhost` on this Windows 7 computer, it says `ftp: connect: Connection refused`. Most likely, this error is not shown for you for whatever reason. You could try a command like `ls` (list files) or `rstatus` (remote status). Most likely, you'll find that the result is a simple `Not connected.` message.

As for why you don't see the `ftp: connect: Connection refused` message, perhaps `stderr` output is discarded for whatever reason. However, `Not connected.` when giving one of the commands suggested above goes to `stdout`, not `stderr` and should be still be visible.

Comment: Is there any way, I can check if the server at the IP `xx.xx.xx.xx` is running FTP server ?

Comment: The simplest way: try `ftp`'ing to the IP address and see what happens. See if you get a login prompt. See if the `ls` command on the FTP prompt gives `Not connected.`.

Comment: http://i39.tinypic.com/14v5mjc.jpg shows what I get

Comment: The Windows command prompt, like Linux/UNIX has two pipes that a program can send output to, `stdout` and `stderr`. Just like you can pipe the main output of a program to a file with `somecommand > output.txt` you can collect (some) error output with `somecommand 2> errors.txt`. What is happening to you is that this error output is hidden. Why, I don't know, but it is. Maybe buggy security software? See example: http://i.imgur.com/12I3uqE.png In other words, there is no FTP server  running, but the error message is hidden. You could try `ftp localhost 2> err.txt` and see if you get something.

Comment: and how do you know that there is no `ftp server` running ?

Comment: Because the output in your screenshot matches the one where I simulate missing error output by piping `stderr` to `nul`. If nothing else, look at what `ls` outputs, `Not connected.`. If you were connected, it would instead show `200 PORT command successful` and a file listing, if there were files in the directory.